Is the current stack page shared after fork useing COW?
I understand the the COW mechnisem causes all the parent and child pages to point to the same frames and that it also includes the stack. However, I am not sure what is the situation of  the current stack page after the fork. Is it still being shared between the two procccess and the first write to stack will cause a page fault?
if(fork () == 0){
char tmp = 'a';
}
else{
char temp2 ='a';
wait();
}

Assuming that the parent process runs first, will the line: "char temp2 ='a';" cause a page fault?
Or maybe becuase the fork itself writes to the stack it will cause the page fault?


However, I am not sure what is the situation of the current stack page after the fork. Is it still being shared between the two processes and the first write to stack will cause a page fault?

The key idea of fork is that a child process gets its own separate and independent copy of the parent process address space. Copy-on-write is an under-the-hood optimization to make the copy cheap, but the behaviour must be that of a complete and independent private copy of the address space (explicit shared file mappings remain shared).
The stack page frames are also copy-on-write shared by fork. For both parent and child processes. Objects allocated on the stack in the parent process retain their original addresses in the child, otherwise the address space copy requirement of fork would be violated.
A first store into a copy-on-write page (in either child or parent process) creates a process-private copy of the original page frame. There are optimizations to avoid copying a page frame when it is no longer COW-shared with any other processes.
Just to be clear, a page frame is a physical memory page backing a (virtual memory) page.
In Linux, fork, vfork and pthread_create are implemented by clone syscall. pthread_create uses CLONE_VM option to share the address space of the calling thread with a newly created thread. I.e. either entire virtual address space is copied or not, no shades of grey in between.
